# .NET Try/Catch Block. Resume?

Tags: .net, try-catch

I've been using a try-catch block to catch an exception but when I do my code doesn't resume. I thought that was the point of catching the exception, to handle the error and then resume. Anyway, I got to it and and wrote code that would generate errors. My intention was to catch all of them until their were no more errors. For example:

```
Try
    strFileSearch = Directory.GetFiles("C:\", "*.wav", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
    MessageBox.Show("Hello World!")
End Try
```

It catches the exception but never resumes so I can't catch other errors.

Comment: What do you mean the code does not resume?

Comment: It just never continues. I wanted it to continue so I could keep catching errors until finally the search was done.

Answer (score 0):

You're catching a unique exception 'UnauthorizedAccessException'. Therefore, if your application throws anything other than an UnauthorizedAccessException (IOException, ArgumentException, etc) your application comes to a halt.

Try catching the base class 'Exception'

```
Try
    strFileSearch = Directory.GetFiles("C:\", "*.wav", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Hello World!")
End Try
```

If you're trying to catch multiple exceptions you can do so by -

```
    Try
        strFileSearch = Directory.GetFiles("C:\", "*.wav", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
        MessageBox.Show("Unathorized Exception!")
    Catch ex As IOException
        MessageBox.Show("IOException!")
    Catch ex As PathTooLongException
        MessageBox.Show("Path To Long Exception!")
    End Try
```

Comment: Well I thought I'd try proper error handling. I could just not respond to the errors and be on with it.

Comment: Understood, with your example you're trying to catch an UnauthorizedAccessException. This may not be the Exception the Directory.GetFiles() method may be throwing. It may be throwing something else. Are you able to share the error message?

Comment: Sure, this error occurs because of trying to access the recycling bin. I was expecting a lot of errors I just thought I could keep handling them all.

Comment: I tried catching a regular exception and it does catch it. But there's no resuming. It doesn't show any cpu usage afterward.

Comment: I edited my answer to display how to catch multiple exemptions in the event that you wanted to catch them individually. Hope that helps.

Comment: Your last exception handler, should be of type Exception, to catch any remaining exceptions.  Catch ex as Exception

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you've misunderstood the intention of Exceptions.

They are not a general error mechanism, but more of a exceptional circumstance error.

So for example, a record not being in a database, could be a general error, no such records, whereas, cannot connect to database (which should be there) would be an exception.

When you use a try catch block, you're saying try this operation, until it throws an exception, then catch the Exceptional circumstance, and after that block, continue with the rest of the program (unless you rethrow).

```
b = 1;

Try
    strFileSearch = Directory.GetFiles("C:\", "*.wav", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    b = 2;
Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
    MessageBox.Show("Hello World!")
End Try

b = b + 1;
```

If your Directory.GetFiles throws an exception, then b at the end of the program would be 2.

```
b = 1
(try block exited early)
b = b + 1;
```

If it didn't throw an exception b would be 3.

```
b = 1
b = 2 (inside the try block)
b = b + 1;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Re-reading the question, it's unclear what the problem is, incorrect exception handling or expecting the Directory.GetFiles to look at each file.

Comment: To be honest I think it's logical at this point. The code so far has caught only 2 exceptions for which they're handled but it's running now for 17 minutes and their's been barely any cpu usage. By now it should of found all my wav files.

Comment: @Neil - the very first time it gets an UnathorizedAccessException, it will exit the try block, jump to the Catch block, and continue with the rest of the program, it will NOT continue to do any work inside the try block, so if the very first file raised a UnathorizedAccessException, then that's it done. Does that make sense?

Comment: mrdnk, yes that totally explains it! In other words I have to go back to a bloated recursive search.

Comment: Check out the meaning of the Exception... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: "UnauthorizedAccessException:
The caller does not have the required permission." This means your program does not have the required permission to get the files. E.g increase the permissions of the program. Probably means, start Visual Studio as an Administrator

Comment: Might be worth, getting the exception message.  Change MessageBox,Show(ex.Message), so even better put a breakpoint after the Catch ex As Exception, and see what the ex contains (e.g. on Message.Show(...)

Comment: so I changed the permission to administrator and the used the try-catch with just Exception instead of unauthorized. The code ran but almost immediately returned no results. Strange, I have a lot of wav files on my computer. I don't know to do now besides forget the one liner and go back to a recursive search. Thanks for all your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Neilno problem. Have a look in the example here, might work better - don't know... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3